# What does the << operator do in this Ruby function?

Tags: ruby

I am confused about what the `<<` operator does.

```
def reconstruct_path(prev, current)
  if prev.include? current
    p = reconstruct_path(prev, prev[current])
    [p] << current
  else
    current
  end
end
```

Comment: `[p]` constructs an array with one element, `p`.  The `Array#<<`  operator is documented here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C.   It is used to add `current` to the array.  It would have made more sense to just write `[p, current]` on that line though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) is known as the "shovel". It pushes "things" into other "things".

Like this in this example:

```
thing_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
thing_array << 6

Result: => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So the array `thing_array` was created with the numbers 1 to 5. By using the shovel it pushes the new entry `6` into the `thing_array`. It's just a shortcut to make code cleaner and lighter.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Nitpicking, but `Array#<<` only pushes "things" into _arrays_. Operators that are implemented as methods have class specific meaning and behavior (e.g. `Integer#<<`). They don’t work on arbitrary objects / receivers.

Comment: Valid point. I don't often use the correct terms, instead using the ones that seem right in my head. But for someone new, it's definitely a good idea to use the right terminology. I'll remember that for the future. Thanks!